# Parameter doesn't perform as well as hard coding the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that performs terribly. When I declare a variable, set its value and then use it in the where clause the statement takes over an hour to run. When I hard code the variables in the where clause it runs in less than a second.

I started to look into what was wrong with it through execution plans. It looks like when I try and pass it some declared variables the execution plan crates some Hash Match because it selects values from a view that uses a UNION and a common table expression.

```
/*************   Begin of Stored Procedure ***************/
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFruit
  @ColorId bigint,
  @SeasionId bigint
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
    A.Name
FROM
    [Apple_View] A   /* This is the view down below */
    INNER JOIN [Fruit] F
        ON ( F.ColorId = @ColorId
            AND A.FruitId = F.FruitId)          
WHERE
    (A.ColorId = @ColorId
    AND 
    A.SeasonId = @SeasonId)

END
/************* End of Stored Procedure   ***************/

/************* Begin of View   ***************/
WITH Fruits (FruitId, ColorId, SeasonId) AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT
        F.FruitId
        ,F.ColorId
        ,F.SeasonId
    FROM
        ((  
            SELECT DISTINCT
                EF.FruitId
                ,EF.ColorId
                ,EF.SeasonId
                ,EF.ParentFruitId
            FROM
                ExoticFruit EF
                INNER JOIN Fruit FR
                    ON FR.FruitId = EF.FruitId
        UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT
                SF.FruitId
                ,SF.ColorId
                ,SF.SeasonId
                ,SF.ParentFruitId               
            FROM
                StinkyFruit SF
                INNER JOIN Fruit FR
                    ON FR.FruitId = SF.FruitId
        UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT
                CF.FruitId
                ,CF.ColorId
                ,CF.SeasonId
                ,CF.ParentFruitId
            FROM
                CrazyFruit CF
                INNER JOIN Fruit FR
                    ON FR.FruitId = CF.FruitId

            )) f

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive Parent Fruit
    SELECT 
        FS.FruitId
        ,FS.ColorId
        ,FS.SeasonId
        ,FS.ParentFruitId
    FROM
        Fruits FS
        INNER JOIN MasterFruit MF
            ON  MF.[ParentFruitId] = fs.[FruitId]
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    FS.FruitId
    ,FS.ColorId
    ,FS.SeasonId
    FROM
        Fruits FS

/************* End of View   ***************/


/* To Execute */
EXEC GetFruit 1,3
```

If I run the Stored Procedure using the set values it takes over an hour and here is the execution plan.
[image: With Variables]

If I run the Stored Procedure removing the DECLARE and SET values and just set the Where clause to the following statement it runs in less than a second and here is the execution plan:

```sql
WHERE(A.ColorId = 1 AND  A.SeasonId = 3)
```

[image: hard coded where clause]

Notice how the hard coded variables uses indexing while the first uses a hash set. Why is that? Why are hard coded values in the where clause working different from the declared variables?

**-------this is what finally performed with the help of @user1166147------**

I changed the stored procedure to use sp_executesql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFruit
  @ColorId bigint,
  @SeasionId bigint
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SelectString nvarchar(max)

SET @SelectString = N'SELECT
    A.Name
FROM
    [Apple_View] A   /* This is the view down below */
    INNER JOIN [Fruit] F
        ON ( F.ColorId = @ColorId
            AND A.FruitId = F.FruitId)          
WHERE
    (A.ColorId = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @ColorId) + '
    AND 
    A.SeasonId = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @SeasonId) + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SelectString

END
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your parameter data types match the column data types?

Comment: These are variables not parameters. SQL Server doesn't do variable sniffing so selectivity estimates will be guesses. What if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: use option recompile .There is something called parameter sniffing in which sql server generates different query plan depending on the input values

Comment: Funny, I didn't notice they were local variables. In addition to using `OPTION RECOMPILE` and the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` setting, I've overcome this in the past by moving the local variable declarations to the parameter list, with default values, to give the optimizer more visibility.

Comment: instead of directly using the input variable in your where clause you can create 2 new variable of the same data type as the input and then try assigning them with the input values and use the new variables in your where clause .In this way sql server will create the same query plan irrespective of the input values

Comment: @praveen - They are already using variables. Which is presumably the problem.

Comment: I actually meant CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP]
  @@ColorId bigint,
  @@SeasonId bigint
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
DECLARE @@ColorId DATETIME;
DECLARE @@SeasonId DATETIME;

Comment: @MartinSmith : anyways i thot he declared those variables in order to hard code it inside his SP .Should hv seen his SP properly .my mistake

Comment: @praveen - The OP has edited their question now and replaced the variables with parameters anyway so back to parameter sniffing then...

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I've edited the question above to reflect your suggestions, however still no luck.  @Aaron we are on SQL 2005 so I don't think I have the option to turn on 'optimize for ad hoc workloads' do I?

Comment: @MartinSmith I've tried fixing it using the Parameter Sniffing "duplicate" you are pointing this question at and tried 'OPTION(RECOMPILE)' and it still doesn't perform any faster.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem as given? i.e. identify why this query is performing badly or would you take an alternate SQL solution that should be quicker? I'm guessing the former as the exec plan doesn't match the SQL given.

Comment: @Mark - Well if you've changed the text of the stored procedure then it won't be using the cached plan anyway. You would need to show us the actual code and execution plans (I assume that you aren't actually querying tables of fruits!)

Comment: @MikeMiller I am hoping to figure out why its performing so poorly because its in a financial production system that I can't easily re-write. I really first need to understand why a parameter passed in performs horribly compared to just running the select statement with hard coded variables

Comment: Is this your actual stored proc?  Parameter sniffing can help - but it has to have  typical parameters values to create the plan well. Try calling the query inside the sproc with Use sp_executesql to execute the affected queries and see if it's better.  If someone else wrote this - they may have intentionally 'disabled' parameter sniffing for a reason.

Comment: You may get more mileage over on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Pretty sure this is getting up-voted just for the frenzied comments not the quality of the question.  Very little information has been given that actual helps solve the issue, i.e. the distribution of data  and the real SQL.  IMHO this is unsolvable in the current form of the question, sorry.

Comment: @MikeMiller, this is 95% the real SQL, the only changes I made were column names and table names to protect our financial system. So I gave you all the information I could, if you need more I can provide more. I've been answering everything I can. I apologize that you are frustratd by the quality of my question, I did the best I could do without exposing our proprietary information.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the Option(Recompile) after further analysis it still didn't perform as fast took on average about 15 minutes to run, compared to over multiple hours before adding the recompile option. It still didn't perform as fast as hard coded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT SUMMARY**  Per a request from  Damien_The_Unbeliever

The goal is to get best/most information about the variable value to SQL BEFORE the plan is created, generally parameter sniffing does this.  There may be a reason that parameter sniffing was 'disabled' in this case.  Without seeing a better representation of the actual code we can't really say what the solution is or why the problem exists.  Try the things below to force the affected areas to generate plans using actual values.

**LONG VERSION WITH MORE DETAIL **

Is this your actual stored proc?  Do you have default values for your parameters?  If so, what are they?

Parameter sniffing can help - but it has to have typical parameters values to create the plan well, and if not, won't really help or will create a bad plan based off of the non typical parameter value.  So if a variable has a default value of null or a value that is not a typical value the first time it is run and the plan compiled - it creates a bad plan.

If someone else wrote this sproc - they may have intentionally 'disabled' parameter sniffing with the local variables for a reason. Business rules may require these variable structures.

The goal is to get best/most information about the variable value to SQL BEFORE the plan is created, and generally Parameter Sniffing does this.  But there are things that can make it affect performance negatively, and that may be why it is 'disabled'.  It still seems like the plan is being created with atypical values for the parameters or not enough info still - using parameter sniffing or not.

Try calling the query inside the sproc with Use sp_executesql to execute the affected queries, forcing it to generate a plan for that area with the actual variables, and see if it's better. This may be your solution if you have to have this sort of irregular parameter value  - create stored procs that run the affected parts and call them later from within the stored procedure - after the variable has received a typical value.

Without seeing a better representation of the actual code, it is hard to see what the problem is.  Hopefully this info will help -

Comment: Whilst your in an editing mood - at the moment, this is just a wall of text. Maybe try breaking it up into paragraphs?

Comment: It's not the actual stored procedure. It is 95% accurate, it just has column names changes to keep the table names and columns private since its a financial system.   *I know it sucks and makes it harder. I apologize i had to do that, but did my best to make it as close as I could with minimal changes

Comment: I was able to get it to perform in less than a second by using 'sp_executesql'. I will put the solution up in my question for future users.

Comment: I get it.  Obviously you can't post your company details.  I guessed as best I could and I am glad it's better.

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to optimize your query based on the typical values that you may know better.
To your original query add the following:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@ColorId = 1, @SeasionId = 3))
```

It would have similar effect without dynamic SQL.
If you don't know the typical values, you can make optimizer sniffing them:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Again, no dynamic SQL